# unit test NotifyPropertyChanged()

Tags: c#, unit-testing

What is the best way to test this property:

```
  public string ThreadId {
        get { return _threadId; }
        set {
            _threadId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I have this test so far:

```
    [Fact]
    public void ThreadIdTest() {
        compassLogData.ThreadId = "[11]";
        const string expected = "[11]";
        string actual = compassLogData.ThreadId;
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
```

but i need a away to test  `NotifyPropertyChanged()` which is used to 
update the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way would be to do this:

```
var notified = false;
compassLogData.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "ThreadId")
        notified = true;
};

compassLogData.ThreadId = "[11]";
Assert.True(notified);
```

Comment: It would be good practice to use `nameof` in the property name check. Assuming the class above is named CompassLogData, this would be: 
`if(e.PropertyName == nameof(CompassLogData.ThreadId))`
This makes it robust against property name changes.

Answer (score 1):

When testing events I use this pattern:

```
[Test]
public void PropertyChangeTest()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    var args = new List<PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
    viewModel.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => args.Add(e);
    viewModel.ThreadId = "[11]";
    Assert.AreEqual("ThreadId",args.Single().PropertyName);
}
```

Adding the eventargses to a list enables checking the number of times it was fired etc.

Usually I don't really see a point in testing that little logic tbh.

Comment: If you are already employing a list, you should not use `Single`. Instead use `Contains`, because it is very possible that setting one property raises multiple notifications. That's always the case when setting one property influences the values of other properties.

Comment: Yes that is true but in this instance i wanted to test that there was only one event fired. Of course it would be clearer to have a separate assert for the count.

Comment: Indeed, you should have a separate test for that case. And it should have a speaking name ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the property-changed-event, and check if is is fired for the correct property.

```
[Fact]
public void ThreadIdTest() {
    compassLogData.ThreadId = "[11]";
    var previousValue = compassLogData.ThreadId; // Question: how is this object set?
    bool propertyWasUpdated = false;
    compassLogData.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ThreadId") {
            propertyWasUpdated = true;
        }
    };

    const string expected = "[12]";
    compassLogData.ThreadId = expected;
    string actual = compassLogData.ThreadId;

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    ASsert.IsTrue(propertyWasUpdated);
}
```

On a separate note, you should only fire the event when the value actually changes. I usually implement it like this:

```
public string ThreadId {
    get { return _threadId; }
    set {
        if (value != _threadId) {
            _threadId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above has potential for false negatives because an event is involved. Ideally you should use a strategy to block the test until the event has fired (such as an AutoResetEvent)

Comment: @bryanbcook Please explain since I do not get what you mean with 'because an event is involved'. Block what test, the if?

Comment: when testing anything related to events you can have a race condition where the assert happens before the event is raised - the test fails indeterminably. Create an AutoResetEvent and in your lambda for the event call Set(); before the assert use WaitOne(timeout) to pause the test until the event is raised.

Comment: But with events are fired sequentially on the current thread (unless specifically executed otherwise), so how could the assert then happen before the event fires?