# Unit test events in VS2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to listen for an event from my custom library, and use that as the basis for a unit test passing or failing -> for instance, if I have a login method I'd like to listen for LoginSucceeded or LoginFailed and pass/fail my unit tests accordingly.  Any clues how to get this working?

Comment: I do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14706181/1069200) when testing events.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the framework you're using. If you use MOQ, you can do something like this:

```
someMockObj.Raise(m=>m.MyEvent += null, anyParam)
```

It seems you want to test the behavior of your code, so the library is a dependency that'll raise some events. I'd mock the library, and raise event like that and test the behavior of your code when the event is raised.